# The response status was: 401 Unauthorized - neo4j

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I successfully installed neo4j changed the default password "neo4j" to some other password.

Install example movie database from the guide

> :play movies

Here is my console application code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
         {
           var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
           client.Connect();
           //query
           var results = client.Cypher
                         .Match(
                         "(actor:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie:Movie {title: {nameParam}})",
                         "(movie)<-[:DIRECTED]-(director:Person)"
                         )
                         .Return((actor, director, movie) => new
                         {
                             Movie = movie.As<Movie>(),
                             Actors = actor.CollectAs<Person>(),
                             Director = director.As<Person>()
                         })
                         .Results.Single();

               Console.WriteLine("{results.Movie.Title} directed by {results.Director.name}");
               foreach (var actor in results.Actors)
               {
               Console.WriteLine("\t{actor.name}");
               }
    }
```

but got an error of

```
The response from Neo4j (which might include useful detail!) was: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized",
    "message" : "No authentication header supplied."
   } ]
}
```

I even change

> dbms.security.auth_enabled=True

to false still, does not solve the problem

Comment: After changed the parameter `dbms.security.auth_enabled` to `False`, have you restarted neo4j service?

Comment: yes, I restarted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the username and password when creating the `GraphClient` instance. Something like:

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "neo4j", "mypassword");
```

Also, when some line is changed in the `neo4j.conf` file, you should restart the neo4j service.